# Linq2db InvalidCastException when table merging

Tags: c#, orm, linq2db

I'm trying update table Registry with List of my own class objects. I found that I [should use temp tables](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/277) for merge with my collection.

```
var tsource = Content.GroupBy(l => l.CardId).Select(s => new DocumentContent
    {
       CardId = s.Key,
       Quantity = s.Sum(c=> c.Quantity),
    }).ToList();
var tempTable = db.CreateTable<DocumentContent>("#tmp");
tempTable.BulkCopy(tsource);
var source = tempTable.Select(s => s);
```

and then [merge](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/wiki/Merge-API) this temp table with target table.

```
db.GetTable<Registry>()
.Merge()
.Using(source)
.On(s => s.CardId, f => f.CardId)
.UpdateWhenMatched((t, s) => new Registry()
{
   Quantity = t.Quantity + s.Quantity,
})
.Merge();
```

But when I use Merge operation I'm getting InvalidCastException in

```
 LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.AllJoinsLinqBuilder.BuildMethodCall(ExpressionBuilder builder, MethodCallExpression methodCall, BuildInfo buildInfo)
```

in \LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\AllJoinsLinqBuilder.cs:line 44

What is the reason for this? What's wrong?

**upd**

Stack trace

```
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.AllJoinsLinqBuilder.BuildMethodCall(ExpressionBuilder builder, MethodCallExpression methodCall, BuildInfo buildInfo) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\AllJoinsLinqBuilder.cs:line 44
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.BuildSequence(BuildInfo buildInfo) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\ExpressionBuilder.cs:line 175
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ContextParser.BuildSequence(ExpressionBuilder builder, BuildInfo buildInfo) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\ContextParser.cs:line 22
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.BuildSequence(BuildInfo buildInfo) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\ExpressionBuilder.cs:line 175
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.Build[T]() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\ExpressionBuilder.cs:line 146
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.CreateQuery(IDataContext dataContext, Expression expr) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Query.cs:line 280
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.GetQuery(IDataContext dataContext, Expression& expr) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Query.cs:line 233
   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.GetQuery(Expression& expression, Boolean cache) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\ExpressionQuery.cs:line 84
   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\ExpressionQuery.cs:line 165
   at LinqToDB.DataProvider.BasicMergeBuilder`2.BuildPredicateByKeys(Type keyType, Expression targetKey, Expression sourceKey) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\DataProvider\BasicMergeBuilder.cs:line 97
   at LinqToDB.DataProvider.BasicMergeBuilder`2.BuildMatch() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\DataProvider\BasicMergeBuilder.cs:line 561
   at LinqToDB.DataProvider.BasicMergeBuilder`2.BuildCommandText() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\DataProvider\BasicMergeBuilder.cs:line 646
   at LinqToDB.DataProvider.BasicMergeBuilder`2.BuildCommand() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\DataProvider\BasicMergeBuilder.cs:line 1265
   at LinqToDB.DataProvider.DataProviderBase.Merge[TTarget,TSource](DataConnection dataConnection, IMergeable`2 merge) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\DataProvider\DataProviderBase.cs:line 481
   at WsMVC.Core.ExpenditurePaper.Incur() in D:\Projects\ProjMVC\MVC\Core\Document.cs:line 225
```

value ex.ToString()

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.AllJoinsLinqBuilder.BuildMethodCall(ExpressionBuilder builder, MethodCallExpression methodCall, BuildInfo buildInfo) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\AllJoinsLinqBuilder.cs:line 44
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.BuildSequence(BuildInfo buildInfo) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\ExpressionBuilder.cs:line 175
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ContextParser.BuildSequence(ExpressionBuilder builder, BuildInfo buildInfo) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\ContextParser.cs:line 22
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.BuildSequence(BuildInfo buildInfo) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\ExpressionBuilder.cs:line 175
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.Build[T]() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Builder\ExpressionBuilder.cs:line 146
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.CreateQuery(IDataContext dataContext, Expression expr) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Query.cs:line 280
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.GetQuery(IDataContext dataContext, Expression& expr) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\Query.cs:line 233
   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.GetQuery(Expression& expression, Boolean cache) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\ExpressionQuery.cs:line 84
   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\Linq\ExpressionQuery.cs:line 165
   at LinqToDB.DataProvider.BasicMergeBuilder`2.BuildPredicateByKeys(Type keyType, Expression targetKey, Expression sourceKey) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\DataProvider\BasicMergeBuilder.cs:line 97
   at LinqToDB.DataProvider.BasicMergeBuilder`2.BuildMatch() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\DataProvider\BasicMergeBuilder.cs:line 561
   at LinqToDB.DataProvider.BasicMergeBuilder`2.BuildCommandText() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\DataProvider\BasicMergeBuilder.cs:line 646
   at LinqToDB.DataProvider.BasicMergeBuilder`2.BuildCommand() in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\DataProvider\BasicMergeBuilder.cs:line 1265
   at LinqToDB.DataProvider.DataProviderBase.Merge[TTarget,TSource](DataConnection dataConnection, IMergeable`2 merge) in C:\projects\linq2db\Source\LinqToDB\DataProvider\DataProviderBase.cs:line 481
   at WsMVC.Core.ExpenditurePaper.Incur() in D:\Projects\ProjMVC\WsMVC\Core\Document.cs:line 225
```

Comment: @mjwills I've edit my post

Comment: this issue was fixed in linq2db 2.4.0